# Warning: array_multisort() [function.array-multisort]: Argument #1 is expected to be an array or a sort flag in

Tags: php, arguments

the following code produces the error in the title. I've tried to google it, but all I got were pages who got the same error (and not an explanation thereof). This isn't really a problem since it's actually working and cancelling the error out with the @ works out just fine. Though I'm still wondering why I haven't been able to execute array_multisort just once without getting this error.

```
public function getMostRelevant(){

  list($occurrences, $keywords) = $this->occurr_keyw_array;


  array_multisort($occurrences, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC,
      $keywords);

  $return_array = array(
         array($occurrences[0], $keywords[0]),
         array($occurrences[1], $keywords[1]),
         array($occurrences[2], $keywords[2])
         );

  return $return_array;

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a check before the function to check if it's an array. For example:

```
if(is_array($occurrences)){ 
     array_multisort($occurrences, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC,$keywords);
}
```

I think this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `$this->occurr_keyw_array` and then `$occurrences` contain what you expect them to contain.

Comment: this is $this->occurr_keyw_array:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 99 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => lung [1] => is [2] => most [3] => important [4] => organ ) )

Comment: does $occurences really contain Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 99 ) after list($occurren.... line?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to declare the arrays you use beforehand:

```
$occurrences = array();
```

It doesn't make sense for me particularly, but it worked here. I suppose it's One More PHP Quirk.